# How to get COUNT of records return by measures in JSON query of CubeJS

Tags: node.js, cube.js

I want to get a count of records return by the below JSON query of CubeJS.

```
{
  "measures": [
    "Employee.salaryTotal"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [
    {
      "dimension": "Employee.createdat"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    "Employee.isactive"
  ],
  "filters": []
}
```

This JSON query generates below SQL in CubeJS:

```sql
SELECT
  `employee`.`isActive` `employee__isactive`,
   SUM(salary) `employee__salary_total`
FROM
  DEMO.Employee AS `employee`
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
LIMIT
  10000
```

Output of SQL is:

```
+---------------------+------------------------+
|  employee__isactive | employee__salary_total |
+---------------------+------------------------+
| Y                   |                  17451 |
| N                   |                   1249 |
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

But what if I want count of records return by above SQL. 
example:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT
      `employee`.`isActive` `employee__isactive`,
      SUM(salary) `employee__salary_total`
    FROM
      DEMO.Employee AS `employee`
    GROUP BY
      1
    ORDER BY
      2 DESC
    LIMIT
      10000) AS EMPSAL
```

Expected result should be like this:

```
+------------+
| # COUNT(*) |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to perform `COUNT` operation on top of final Cube.js query. If you're trying to implement paging functionality you can use `offset` and `limit` query parameters to check if there's a next page available by means of `limit` and row count comparison: https://cube.dev/docs/query-format#query-properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So, in this case, we can not able to show record count but able to paginate records by checking the next page using `offset` and `limit` query parameters.

Comment: Yep. Right. You can also check if current page size equals limit then there're probably some more records pending.